# Конвертация точек полигона из 3D в 2D

Tags: математика

У меня есть набор точек (x, y, z), которые лежат на одной плоскости, которая задана точкий и вектором. Как преобразовать эти точки в 2D?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я полагаю, вектор, который задаёт плоскость - это вектор нормали к плоскости?

Поверните систему координат таким образом, чтобы ось `Z` стала коллинеарна этому вектору. Тогда в новой системе координат `x',y',z'` уравнение плоскости будет `z' == const`

Пусть вектор нормали к плоскости составляет с осью `Z` угол θ, а его проекция на плоскость `XY` образует угол φ.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тогда переход от системы координат `x,y,z` к `x',y',z'` задаётся матрицей

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как выразить эти углы через координаты вектора нормали к плоскости.

Если у вектора нормали к плоскости координаты `u,v,w`, то обозначим длину этого вектора как `R`: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тогда синусы-косинусы через `u,v,w` выражаются так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения], [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама матрица в терминах  `u,v,w` получается такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для вычисления двумерных координат умножьте радиус-вектор `(x,y,z)` на эту матрицу справа и отбросьте значение `Z`.